# Is this solution about unit circle right?

Tags: trigonometry

If cos(x)=-2/pi
Are these solutions for x right:
X=129 and x=230
If they are not correct please correct them

Comment: If $x$ is closed to $90$, $\cos(x)$ is very close to $0$. I am afraid there is something wrong. Could you describe your work ?

Answer (score 0):

If $$cos(x)=-\frac{2}{\pi}$$
Then there are many solutions for $x$ given by
$$x=2n\pi \pm cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)$$ where $$n\in\mathbb Z$$

and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%20inverse%20%28-2%2Fpi%29%20) yields $$cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)=129.5^0\approx2.2609^c$$